# Magento 2.3 Magento 2 Testing Email Sending But Order Confirmation Email Is Not Sending

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

I am using magaplaza SMTP extension and i configured it correctly, Test Email Working Fine But When I place an order the order confirmation email not sending. And the Email Logs Telling me that email is sent but actually email not received.

please see the images below:

Email Logs :

[image]

Configurations:

[image]

Comment: Can u please check your email's spam folder and other folder may be it will be available there

Comment: Yes i check all folders but nothing found

Comment: Check sent folder in gmail whether google sending your email or not. Check delivery status of email.

Comment: There are free email services available. You can try that. That pin point exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that **Developer Mode** is **No** in Developer tab in *MagePlaza SMTP* extension.

[image]

If **Yes** is selected there, then please set **No** there and clear cache once and try again.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Is above solution works for you ?

Comment: Brother its already set to no

Comment: https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app

You can try this. :)

Comment: I try this as well and same happened with magepal extension testing email received but sales emails like order confirmation not sending.

Comment: When you create new customer account at that time you are getting any emails there ?

Comment: i checked when i create new customer from front store i not receive the email

Comment: Can you please check your log files in var log once ?